# Changing just the url of gallery2

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting

I inherited a implementation of [Gallery2](http://galleryproject.org/) embedded in a Drupal site. I need to change the url of the page this is on from /gallery to /somethingelse.

Drupal is not something I am very familiar with, but I've done some stuff here and there with it years ago.

The /gallery page is not listed anywhere in the admin interface and the content is living in page-gallery.tpl.php.

A 301 redirect is going to be necessary (which I do know how to do), but that isn't the solution I'm looking for obviously (just to avoid getting that answer). Is there any simple way to change this url?

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to understand how drupal handle URLs & generate a page based on it. There are several way to have a URL in drupal, where you can navigate from somewhere.

- Usually we make page(add content) of some content type, which you create before with all the required fields. Drupal give serial node number to all newly created page, so to have your own custom URL, you will need to use [PATHAUTO](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which will create URL based on title of the page, though you can modify at time of creating page.
- We create listings of some things e.g. images for gallery by help of [VIEWS](https://drupal.org/project/views) & we can create page for the listing. We get to give URL for the page, which you can edit any time.
- We declare URLs in our custom module under [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Other contributed module also do the same & that's why you get some pages when you enable the module.

Apart from page content, drupal have block system. A block can contains content, image, links etc & display of it can be set to all pages as well as any specific page. So there is no limitation for you to make your page with the URL which you want if you are using PATHAUTO module. If you have listing from views or code which is generating page, then you can always go there & change.